# Add objects to jmonkey scene at runtime

Tags: java, swing, jmonkeyengine

I would like to build a simple graphical editor using JMonkey, where the user can add and modify simple shapes using a swing interface with the right buttons. Is it possible to add the shapes to the existing scene while JMonkey is running in a different way than using simpleUpdate method of SimpleApplication? And if so, how to do that?

Comment: Have you looked into JavaFx2? I know that it doesn't answer your question. However, it' s a solid framework for what you plan on doing. Check out "ensemble javafx 2" to test what it can do! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI: There are already projects that can do that using JMonkeyEngine. Take a look at the forum. The [jMonkeyEngine SDK](http://jmonkeyengine.org/features/editor/) also comes with an integrated scene composer.

---

As long as you have a reference to the `Node` you can manipulate it from wherever you want. But you have to ensure that you don't modify the scenegraph from outside the jME thread. Once you added a node to the scene this will apply to rotating, translating, scaling, modifying materials, attaching/detaching subnodes etc.

You can use `Callable` objects to move the execution of code from the Swing thread to the jME thread: http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3:advanced:multithreading?s[]=threading

The first example in that article shows how to enqueue code to the jME Application. Use `SimpleApplication.getRootNode()` to get the root node from outside. Alternatively you can also use [UpdateControl](http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/javadoc/com/jme3/scene/control/UpdateControl.html) for the same purpose.